# Powershell Inconsistency string

Tags: string, powershell

```
$ServName = "" 

$UnnecessaryService = get-service

$UnnecessaryService | Out-File "UnnecessaryServices.txt"

$UnnecessaryService = gc UnnecessaryServices.txt | Select-String "CryptSvc"

$UnnecessaryService = Out-String -InputObject $UnnecessaryService

$UnnecessaryService = $UnnecessaryService.Split(' ')

$UnnecessaryService = $UnnecessaryService[0]

$NowName = " Cryptographic Services"
write $UnnecessaryService

if ($UnnecessaryService -eq "Running")
{
    $ServName = $ServName + $NowName
    write $ServName
}
else
{
    $result = "good"
    write $result
}
```

I think this codes output must be `$ServName` but it's printed `$result`.
So I find out what is the problem.

Then `$UnnecessaryService` has link break.
The bottom line is i want `$UnnecessaryService -eq "Running"` is correct code. Help me guys.

The contents of **UnnecessaryServices.txt** is:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                                         
Running  CryptSvc           Cryptographic Services
```

Comment: My advice is to redo this code completely because there’s too much seemingly unnecessary file interaction. `$service = Get-Service <service name>; if ($service.status -eq 'Running') # run code `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the output from `Get-Service` to file is unnecessary - instead, you'll want to inspect the `Status` property of the object(s) returned by `Get-Service`:

```
# Get CryptSvc service controller
$cryptSvc = Get-Service CryptSvc

# test if it's running or not
if($cryptSvc.Status -eq 'Running'){
    # CryptSvc IS running
    '{0} is running...' -f $cryptSvc.DisplayName
}
else {
    # CryptSvc is NOT running
}
```